# Quickfixn SSL Configuration issue

Tags: c#, ssl, quickfix, quickfixn

Im trying to configure my quickfix to initiate SSL connection, I tried a lot  ok googling and went with the below configuration and im getting following error. Will be great if some one can  give suggestions on this.

Configuration:

```
    [DEFAULT]
    ConnectionType=initiator
    ReconnectInterval=200
    FileStorePath=E:/Vivek/SourceCodes/Swiss/PrimoLiquidity/PrimeLiquidity/bin/Debug/FixLogs/MarketDataLogs
    FileLogPath=E:/Vivek/SourceCodes/Swiss/PrimoLiquidity/PrimeLiquidity/bin/Debug/FixLogs/MarketDataLogs
    StartTime=00:00:00
    EndTime=00:00:00
    UseDataDictionary=Y
    DataDictionary=E:/Vivek/SourceCodes/Swiss/PrimoLiquidity/PrimeLiquidity/bin/Debug/FIX44.xml
    SocketConnectPort=2525
    SocketConnectHost=70.42.18.200
    ResetOnLogon=Y
    ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
    SSLEnable=Y
    SSLValidateCertificates=N
    SSLCheckCertificateRevocation=N
    SSLCertificate=C:/Users/Vivek/NewCert.pfx
    SSLCertificatePassword=12345


    # standard config elements

    [SESSION]
    BeginString=FIX.4.4
    SenderCompID=quote.DEMOSUCD.530
    SenderSubID=DEMOSUCD
    TargetCompID=demo.fxgrid
    HeartBtInt=30
```

Error:

```
 20170310-19:40:45.089 : Unable to perform authentication against server: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
 20170310-19:40:45.089 : Connection failed (AuthenticationException): A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quickfixn SSL Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725200/quickfixn-ssl-configuration)

Comment: Sorry it got posted twice by mistake, Can you please answer any one of my link?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this extensively before, not through the QuickFIX API but through stunnel. [See here](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html). It think you should use this to set up a persistent SSL connection. It might take a bit of time to configure, but once you get it you don't have to worry about it again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I tried to configure Stunnel and get the below error.                                                2017.03.13 13:55:26 LOG5[1]: Service [demo.fxgrid] accepted connection from 127.0.0.1:51368
2017.03.13 13:55:26 LOG5[1]: s_connect: connected 127.0.0.1:80
2017.03.13 13:55:26 LOG5[1]: Service [demo.fxgrid] connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:51369
2017.03.13 13:55:26 LOG3[1]: SSL_connect: 140770FC: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
2017.03.13 13:55:26 LOG5[1]: Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to TLS, 0 byte(s) sent to socket

Comment: Below are my configs

Comment: [demo.fxgrid]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:443
connect = 70.42.18.200:2525
cert = C:\Users\Vivek\my-cert.pem
key = C:\Users\Vivek\my-key.pem

Comment: QuickFix Config                                                                                                   SocketConnectPort=443
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1

Comment: Sorry if i have made any silly mistakes, Im totally new to this

Answer (score 0):

Where does this error come from - your side or the counterparty side? What's the SSPI inner exception say?

There's something about SSPI and quick fix [here](http://lists.quickfixn.com/pipermail/quickfixn-quickfixn.com/2013q4/002939.html) that the certificate is not in the Windows cert store.

I also agree with Wapiti: use stunnel

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The error comes from my counter party side. I am trying to use Stunnel.